# Problem with trying to display subheader in posts

Tags: posts

On [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Designing_Headings#H3_and_H4_Headings) article, it was said that you can use the `h4` tag to create a subheader to break up long posts. However, whenever I wrap text in the tags, it displays the tags as regular characters. Wordpress doesn't seem to recognize the use of HTML. I have this

```
Hello... blah blah

<h4>And there was freedom!</h4>
```

But it renders exactly the same, with no header. I am using the theme December if that has anything to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You easily add an H4 tag in the "Visual" version of the editor (the tab on the upper right corner of the editor) by selecting the text you want to be the subheader at the top of the rich text editor there is a buttom at the end of the first row of icons called the "Kitchen Sink", click this to expose all the options the editor has available, now select the drop down hich likely says "Paragraph" and change it to "Heading 4".

If you are on the "Text" version of the editor, you would add the `<h4></h4>` tags around your subheading.

Comment: Didn't know about the kitchen sink button! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That Codex page strikes me as somewhat misleading you about the `<h*>` tags. `<h*>` tags ***are not*** formatting tags. The are not shortcuts for font sizes, or text colors, or line breaks. [They are semantic](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html). You should create a meaningful outline of content with those tags, not use them just to "break up long posts".

To say that "Wordpress doesn't seem to recognize the use of HTML" doesn't make any sense. WordPress generates pages for consumption by web browsers. Web browsers "read" HTML. WordPress would not work if it somehow didn't "recognize the use of HTML", but you do have to be careful where you put the `HTML` in the editor. The visual editor can do strange things with markup. That may be where you are going wrong.

As far as how the tags *look*, that is purely CSS. Your theme controls that. If the tags don't look how you'd like, use CSS to change it, but remember that you are dealing with semantic tags and not purely decorative ones.